# Button not responsive when using both MediaRecorder And SensorManager at the same time

Tags: android

I notice in Android Jelly Bean, the buttons are not responsive after a minute of recording on sensor data logger program. Therefore, I set out to build my own.

However, I am running into the same problem as them. My program becomes unresponsive after a minute or so.

Is there anyway to do this properly in Jelly Bean?

I have tried to run things in the background via, Service and Threads but no avail. I might not be using threads properly. I mean how do you define onChangeSensor on the background? Do you spawn threads every time it is called? Seems excessive and probably slow things down more than necessary.

Is there a way to spawn the media recorder and Sensor logger as separate threads to keep the UI responsive and functional?

Answer (score 0):

The first solution was to disable the continuous focus. I found this out by running the same code without the continuous focus on a Nexus S which does not have the continuous focus feature. I had to comment the parameter setting line out or it will return runtimeexception.

The better solution is to set the API to be 16 and run it on Jelly Bean phone. It worked for me on my Galaxy Nexus. I guess just setting the minimum API setting to something higher changes the way it runs in JB?